# Overwrite img vertical align inside table cell (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I need to be able to overwrite vertical align for an image inside a td tag that has a vertical align defined. 
I tried giving the image vertical-align: middle, and while this works in ff, the image still drops below the line in chrome.
The html is provided though bbcode editor.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">
        The text in table cell needs to align to top
        <br/>
        <br/>            

        image should vertically center relative to line <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 200px;
}
td img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6okr7ayy/10/)

works in firefox, but not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the standard the vertical-align property with !important within your CSS:

**UPDATE**

Add a  element to your text and vertical-align your image

```css
td img {
    background: red;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 200px;
}
td img{vertical-align:middle}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">
            The text in table cell needs to align to top The text in table cell needs to align to top The text in table cell needs to align to top
            <br/>
            <br/>            
            
            <span>image should vertically center relative to line</span> <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "vertical-align: top" cannot be changed or removed (its used by bbcode editors for various purposes)

Comment: I modified my code! Now it works with vertical-align:top

Comment: The td needs to keep the top vertical alignment. I updated fiddle to better display the problem.

Comment: The only solution that I can think of is adding a <span> to your text: https://jsfiddle.net/6okr7ayy/13/, I also modified the code snippet again.

Answer (score 0):

Middle vertical align of `td` will fix your problem:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6okr7ayy/7/

---

> "vertical-align: top" cannot be changed or removed (its used by bbcode editors for various purposes)

Then try just to override it in CSS with `!important`

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Comment: "vertical-align: top" cannot be changed or removed (its used by bbcode editors for various purposes)

Comment: The td needs to keep the top vertical alignment. I updated fiddle to better display the problem.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the text and the image inside the td into a paragraph. Now your code works on Chrome too:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <p>The text in table cell needs to align to top
    <br/>
    <br/>image should vertically center relative to line 
    <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS stays at it was:

```
td {
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 200px;
}
td img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6okr7ayy/11/).